# Adding a suffix depending upon singular or plural

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-5

I like to use the correct spelling depending upon there a only one element in the array or multiple elements.
Currently I accomplish that by using the following pattern:

```
const arr = ["Ford", "Renault"];
const message = `${arr.length} car${arr.length > 1 ? "s" : ""} available!`;

console.log(message);
```

**Is there a better way?**
I would like to avoid the unnecessary else-part (... : "").

Comment: Looks just fine to me

Comment: You can't really skip the `else` part, you can have something like `let suffix = "";  arr.length > 1 && (suffix = "s"); const message = ... car${suffix} ...;`, but you replace the `else` by a default value and need a var more.

Comment: @Kaddath Yes. But nevertheless: Cool way of conditional assignment you show there. Thanks a lot for it.

Comment: You're welcome, that was the goal of my comment, as you seemed interested by ways to shorten code. It's often used by minificators